# A term for sequences whose mean is defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, limits-and-convergence

This may be an extremely stupid and elementary question, but is there a name for sequences $\{a_i\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)$ exists? This seems to be a separate condition from boundedness or summability.

Comment: Cesàro summable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: Many thanks.  If you want to submit that as an answer I can go ahead and accept it.

Comment: You're welcome.  I made this into an answer as requested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard term is *Cesàro summable*, named after [Ernesto Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernesto_Ces%C3%A0ro).  Note that a convergent sequence is also Cesàro summable (with the same limit), but the converse does not always hold.

**Edit.** I realize that there is some confusion, thanks to the comments of Hurkyl and jeq below.  *Cesàro summable* is usually a property attributed to a series $\sum_i b_i$.  We recover the right definition for sequences by regarding the sequence $(a_i)$ as the series $\sum_i b_i$, where $b_1=a_1$ and $b_i=a_i-a_{i-1}$.  I think *Cesàro convergent* is probably a better term to use for sequences.

Comment: Perhaps Cesaro _mean_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean?

Comment: No, the Cesàro means are the sequence of partial averages.  A sequence is Cesàro summable if the sequence of Cesàro means converges.

Comment: This answer is wrong, according to the wikipedia link. If $a_n$ was the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_k b_k$, then the limit the OP asks about is the Cesaro sum of $\sum_k b_k$.

Comment: The OP's question, I believe, was for a term for when the limit of a sequence of partial averages exists. The sequence $\lbrace 1,1,...\rbrace$ has a Cesàro mean, but is not Cesàro summable.

Comment: It is correct.  The confusion is the distinction between a series and a sequence.  In the wikipedia link provided by @jeq, Cesàro summability is defined as a property of *sequences*, while in my link above it is defined as a property of *series*.  The property that the OP wants is that the *sequence* $a_i$ is Cesàro summable, not that the series $\sum a_i$ is Cesàro summable.

Comment: @jeq The sequence $1, 1,  \dots, $ is Cesàro summable, with Cesàro limit $1$, but the series $\sum_i 1$ is not Cesàro summable.

Comment: I guess Cesàro summable is not a really good term when applied to a sequence.  I think we used *Cesàro convergent* when I was an undergrad.  Then again, a series is a sequence and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The unambiguous name for a sequence with converging Cesàro means of its terms, is *Cesàro convergent sequence*.
The unambiguous name for a sequence with converging Cesàro means of its partial sums, is *Cesàro summable sequence*.

Now about 'series'. Cauchy (1821, Cours d'Analyse p. 123) described *series* (French *série*) as a sequence with real numbers as terms. (In later practice extended to: a sequence with addable (addible?) elements as terms.)
Unfortunately Cauchy proposed and used *convergent* (French *convergente*) instead of *summable* (French *sommable)* for a sequence/series with converging partial sums.  Which resulted - worldwide - in a double meaning for *convergent*:

- *convergent* means *having a sum* in combination with the word *series*,
- *convergent* means *having a limit* in combination with the word *sequence*.

Conclusion: *Cesàro convergent series* and *Cesàro summable series* are synonym. But *Cesàro convergent sequence* and *Cesàro summable sequence* are NOT.